# Covariant Return Types of Objects

Tags: c++, class, oop, object

The following code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <stdio.h>


class mother {
    public:
     virtual mother* display() {};
};

class daughter : public mother
{
    public:
    daughter* display()
    {
        daughter *d1 = new daughter();
        std::cout << "This is the daughter" << std::endl;
        return d1;
    }

    void signature()
    {
        cout<<"I'm the sign"<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    //code
    mother *w = new daughter();
    daughter *w2 = w->display();
    w2->signature();
    return 0;
}
```

Returns an error that daughter w2 cannot be assigned from the return value of `w->display()`. But from what I know, display is a virtual function. So `w->display()` should call the daughter variation of the display function, which has a return type of daughter. Then exactly why isn't this working and what could be changed?

Comment: A `mother` cannot become a `daughter`, even though it's a covariant type.
`if (daughter *w2 = dynamic_cast<daughter*>( w->display())) { w2->signature(); }`

Comment: The compiler implicitly converts the return type of `daughter::display` to `mother*`. This is a special rule for covariant return types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct behavior, the code has a mistake:
`mother::display` returns a pointer to `mother`, you are "driving" `display` from a pointer to `mother`, syntactically.  Then you are asking to convert a pointer to `mother` to `daughter`, which is a "downcast", not all `mother`s are `daughters` in your hierarchy, so, you have to use an explicit cast.  This is the syntax.

You "know" the *real* object is of type `daughter`, so, it will return a type of `mother` that is a `daughter`, but this is not said in the syntax.  The compiler will not go and practically execute your source code to compile it, that is not how it works.

You can do this:

```
daughter *w2 = static_cast<daughter *>(w->display());
```

or

```
daughter *w2 = dynamic_cast<daughter *>(w->display());
```

Use `static_cast` only if you can prove the object is indeed of the type you say it is, `dynamic_cast` (and test) otherwise.  `static_cast` has no penalty, the compiler "trusts" you.

Comment: What if we have more derived class objects and we do not know at the moment which is the real object ( i.e son or daughter ). But we call mother display func and we want to execute the display function corresponding to the derived class which we will initialize later. How can do that?