# Covariant Return Type and Object Oriented Programming

Tags: c++, function, class, oop, object

I have a super class defined.

```
class Region
{
public:
    virtual Region translate(int x,int y);
    virtual bool contains(struct point p);
};
```

Now I have a subclass defined as Union which basically takes union of two regions.

```
class Union : public Region
{
    Region r1,r2;

    Union translate(int x,int y) {
        Union translated;
        translated.r1 = r1.translate(x,y);
        translated.r2 = r2.translate(x,y);
        translated.rotateangle=rotateangle;
        return translated;
    }
};
```

Now I have regions defined specifically as the subclass of region namely Rectangle, Triangle and Circle which have their own translate function with the same return type. (i.e Triangle translate has a return type of triangle. )

Example code :

```
class Triangle : public Region
{
private:

    struct point A,B,C;

public:

    Triangle translate(int x,int y)
    {
        Triangle translated;

        translated.A.x+=x;
        translated.B.x+=x;
        translated.C.x+=x;

        translated.A.y+=y;
        translated.B.y+=y;
        translated.C.y+=y;

        return translated;
    }
};
```

As we can see that in the Union class, we are taking union of two regions about which we don't know from which subclass they belong ( i.e whether they are triangle, circle or rectangle ) but we still want to translate the regions r1 and r2 calling translate function on each on them.

Since we cannot call translate on r1 and r2 without knowing their types, how can we implement this functionality to achieve this hierarchy?

Comment: This is a flashing red flag: `class Union : public Region { Region r1,r2; ...` that I read as _"a `Union` is a `Region` containing two `Region`s"_.

Comment: Note that covariance (and contravariance) only applies to pointers and references in C++.

Comment: `translated.rotateangle` what does this mean? There's no member named `rotateangle`

Comment: Why do you think you couldn't call `translate` on `r1` and `r2`? That's exactly what interfaces (aka pure virtual classes) are used for.

Comment: please review your example code, certain things are fishy and details do matter. First the mixture of composition and inheritance that was already mentioned then `Region::translate` returns a pointer, but `Triangle::translate` returns a `Triangle`.

Comment: Please include in your question minimal working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store `Region`s by reference or pointer in `Union`. As it stands you *can't* store `Triangle`s, `Rectangle`s etc in `Union`, you will copy the (empty?) `Region` base sub-object.

Something like

```
#include <memory>

struct Point
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
};

class Region
{
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Region> translate(int x,int y) = 0;
    virtual bool contains(Point p) = 0;
};

class Union : public Region
{
    std::unique_ptr<Region> r1, r2;
    int rotateangle;
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Region> translate(int x,int y) override {
        auto translated = new Union;

        translated->r1 = r1->translate(x,y);
        translated->r2 = r2->translate(x,y);
        translated->rotateangle = rotateangle;

        return std::unique_ptr<Region>(translated);
    }

    bool contains(Point p) override {
        return r1->contains(p) || r2->contains(p);
    }
};

class Triangle : public Region
{
    Point A,B,C;
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Region> translate(int x,int y) override {
        auto translated = new Triangle;

        translated->A.x = A.x + x;
        translated->B.x = B.x + x;
        translated->C.x = C.x + x;

        translated->A.y = A.y + y;
        translated->B.y = B.y + y;
        translated->C.y = C.y + y;

        return std::unique_ptr<Region>(translated);
    }

    bool contains(Point p) override {
        return false; // TODO
    }
};
```

Note that you *don't* have to know that `Union::translate` has returned a (pointer to) `Union`.

Comment: In the class Union. r1 and r2 are pointers of the class region. Now when we are doing ```r1->translate(x,y)``` we are down-casting the pointer type ( As in a region can be a triangle, rectangle or circle. ) So don't we need to explicitly typecast it? [As from this question for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60482749/covariant-return-types-of-objects)

Comment: The *point* of virtual functions is that you call the most derived version. Note that `Region::translate` *lacks* a definition.

Comment: So basically what I understand is, in the translate function inside the triangle class, we are returning a region pointer instead of a triangle pointer. ```return std::unique_ptr<Region>(translated);``` That is what this line of code means right?

Comment: @KudoShinichi Yes, you are returning a pointer-to-Region, which points to a `Triangle`